# iCACLS with variable for username in VBS

Tags: vbscript, icacls

Hoping someone can help as I can't quite figure this one out :(

I have the following vbs to set permissions to a list of sub folders within a specified directory (C:\test) and based on a specified user account (Test1);

```
    Dim intRunError, objShell, objFSO

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder("c:\Test").SubFolders
        If objFSO.FolderExists(objFolder) Then
            intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| icacls " _
            & objFolder & " /grant:r Test1:(OI)(CI)F /T", 2, True)

            If intRunError <> 0 Then
                Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
                & objFolder.Name & " to the folder " & objFolder
        End If
    End If

 Next
```

This all works fine. However, what i really want is to use a variable for the account that will get the permissions set. In my case, the name of the folder will always be the correct username. So I had hoped to use a variable such as:

```
& objFolder & " /grant:r objFolder.Name:(OI)(CI)F /T", 2, True)
```

However, clearly that doesn't work as its being written as a literal string. I've tried a few formatting variations but can't seem to get it to do what i need.

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks in advance!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, should have been:

```
& objFolder & " /grant:r " & objFolder.Name & ":(OI)(CI)F /T", 2, True)
```

Adam